# file pathname is not found on the production mode using fs.writeFile

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, node.js-fs

i have a api route in my nextjs project and i'm using fs.writeFile method such as
   `await fs.writeFile( process.cwd() + '/app/data/list.json', data )`
It is working properly on development and local production mode, but not working on the vercel build. It throws an error `code: "ENOENT" errno: -2` meaning that file not found
What should i do to make it work properly on the vercel build, and why is that happening?

I tried __dirname instead of process.cwd() but not worked

Comment: Not sure you have access to the file system on Vercel. Might need something like https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-blob

Comment: it searchs at the wrong pathname, but i don't know how to make it correct

Comment: I still don't think you can achieve this.